How to make combobox in flet?
I'm working on small chat app and frontend of it written in Flet. I would like to add search functionality with following flow:

There's search field in UserControl;
User clicks on this field, enters some value, say Te;
App calls DB with /search route and gets ['Tet', 'Test'] as an answer;
This list of values is shown to user in dropdown where user may select one. If nothing is found ( = [] is returned), Nothing is found option is passed to dropdown.

In simpler terms, I would like to have good old combobox, and as of now, I dont see any ft.ComboBox or similar GUI objects in flet lib.

ft.TextField doesn't have dropdown;
ft.Dropdown doesn't have text field to write anything;

So, how do I implement that?
